# raspberry pi zero w disconnect camera running motioneyeos

Tags: motion

pi zero w running motioneyeos with Noir camera will run for several hours on the motioneye os be fore disconnecting , there are  two other raspberry pi zero w and one raspberry pi 3b plus working  as motioneye server, only  one of the pi zero w will disconnect its camera from the network, the pi power light will remain on , when pi is unplug and plug back in it will work normally for as long as sometimes 12 hours before it disconnects again, tried changing power supply , get same results
thanks for help

Comment: check various logs in `/var/log` for any indication of issues - perhaps `syslog`, `messages`, `debug`, `daemon.log` and `user.log` for a start - and any other logs that motioneyeos may be putting there

Comment: Could you add some punctuation to your question? An actual question mark somewhere would be a good start.